# Sign certificate for localhost

Tags: tls, node.js

I'm using HTTPS Node.js server on my localhost, and every restart (PC), when I go to 'https://localhost' I get the certificate message (Chrome).

I want to ask how to install the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

If it is only for *development* purpose you can add `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;` in your source code or use environment variable on your system with :

```
$ export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

For *production*, it's mostly recommended to use **a trusted CA certificate**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, you can add the root certificate to the Keychain Access application under System Roots keychain.